# Progress bar in struts framework

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have two JSP pages. The first jsp page have one button and bootstrap progress bar. when I click the button go to the action page. In the action action page I have written one method, it will take long process time,so I want to set progress bar value depending up on the process .After finished the process go to the second jsp page. So how can I get the value for progress bar from the action page?

Answer (score 1):

I believe best is to use plain JQuery code with [execute-and-wait-interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/execute-and-wait-interceptor.html).The ExecuteAndWaitInterceptor is great for running long-lived actions in the background while showing the user a nice progress meter, So when the upload is in progress you can keep showing some kind of progress animation to user.You can also play around with [S2-JQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/) also.

You requirement is very similar to file upload in which user wants to show progress bar while the upload is in progress as even in file upload its the Action which do the heavy lifting and take a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Its very late to the question but if still any body is looking to achieve the progress bar functionality can achieve by adding rest nature to struts 1 project using `RestEasy` or `Jersey`, Both will use same application context and server security.

Here is a simple tutorial [how to implement progress bar in Struts 1 using Jersey](https://reptilebirds.blogspot.com/2024/02/creating-progress-bar-in-struts.html)